# Why the difference between two DateTime objects does not work?

Tags: php, datetime, datediff

I've got a problem with my "DateTime difference code":

```
$timeStart = new DateTime('2015-11-28');
$timeEnd = new DateTime('2016-11-28');
$interval = $timeEnd->diff($timeStart);
$result = $interval->format('%d');

echo $result." day(s)";
```

When I visualize $result, PHP show me 0. But between those two dates there are more days than 0 day...

php does not calculate the difference between two dates that are not in the same year?

Comment: No probs, I've shifted the comment into an answer with an answer  for just that question ;D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there are 0 days difference. There is however a 1 year difference. If you changed `%d` to `%y` you'd get 1. So there's a difference of 1 year, 0 months and 0 days.

What you can use instead is the `days` property on `DateInterval`, as such:

`$result = $interval->days;`

Comment: Thanks Jon, but then how do I do to return the number of days between these dates ?

Comment: @Syxmoke Using the code at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: oh sorry, I had not seen your answer, i will test it now.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I'm aware the answer was given already. But below is just a bit explanation.

In fact, [DateInterval::format()](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) does makes sense when you have a fixed amount of time (in years, months, days, hours), like this:

```
$interval = new DateInterval('P2Y4DT6H8M');
echo $interval->format('%d days');
```

**That isn't your case!**
where you have a relative time (2016-11-28 related to 2015-11-28) at all. In this specific case you want the days amount past since 28-11-2015.
That's why `DateInterval::days` (DateTime::diff() returns a [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object) makes sense:

```
$start = new DateTime('2015-11-28');
$end   = new DateTime('2016-12-28');

var_dump($end->diff($start)->days);
```